# Collapse an accordion container with items inside

Tags: css

I have a container with items inside, that I would like to collapse on click. I created a wrapping div on which I can set height: 0, but the problem is that some items inside the container have their own height, so they will still be visible.

The easiest workaround would be to just not render the items inside the container when the button is clicked, but I would like to closing of the accordion to be with animation, as if the according is closing on the items and makes them disappear in a second, and not just disappearing instantly.

Is there maybe an alternative to setting height to 0?

```
.minimizeActive {
     height: 0px;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 50;
}


<div className={classes.minimizeActive}>

  <Segment basic>
    <Card color="teal" fluid>
      {post.picUrl && (
        <Image
          src={post.picUrl}
          style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
          floated="left"
          wrapped
          ui={false}
          alt="PostImage"
          onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}
        />
      )}

      <Card.Content>
        <Image
          floated="left"
          src={post.user.profilePicUrl}
          avatar
          circular
        />

        {(user.role === "root" || post.user._id === user._id) && (
          <>
            <Popup
              on="click"
              position="top right"
              trigger={
                <Image
                  src="/deleteIcon.svg"
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  size="mini"
                  floated="right"
                />
              }
            >
              <Header as="h4" content="Are you sure?" />
              <p>This action is irreversible!</p>

              <Button
                color="red"
                icon="trash"
                content="Delete"
                onClick={() =>
                  deletePost(post._id, setPosts, setShowToastr)
                }
              />
            </Popup>
          </>
        )}

        <Card.Header>
          <Link href={`/${post.user.username}`}>
            <a>{post.user.name}</a>
          </Link>
        </Card.Header>

        <Card.Meta>{calculateTime(post.createdAt)}</Card.Meta>

        {post.location && <Card.Meta content={post.location} />}

        <Card.Description
          style={{
            fontSize: "17px",
            letterSpacing: "0.1px",
            wordSpacing: "0.35px",
          }}
        >
          {post.text}
        </Card.Description>
      </Card.Content>

      <Card.Content extra>
        <Icon
          name={isLiked ? "heart" : "heart outline"}
          color="red"
          style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
          onClick={() =>
            likePost(
              post._id,
              user._id,
              setLikes,
              isLiked ? false : true
            )
          }
        />

        <LikesList
          postId={post._id}
          trigger={
            likes.length > 0 && (
              <span className="spanLikesList">
                {`${likes.length} ${
                  likes.length === 1 ? "like" : "likes"
                }`}
              </span>
            )
          }
        />

        <Icon
          name="comment outline"
          style={{ marginLeft: "7px" }}
          color="blue"
        />

        {comments.length > 0 &&
          comments.map(
            (comment, i) =>
              i < 3 && (
                <PostComments
                  key={comment._id}
                  comment={comment}
                  postId={post._id}
                  user={user}
                  setComments={setComments}
                />
              )
          )}

        {comments.length > 3 && (
          <Button
            content="View More"
            color="teal"
            basic
            circular
            onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}
          />
        )}

        <Divider hidden />

        <CommentInputField
          user={user}
          postId={post._id}
          setComments={setComments}
        />
      </Card.Content>
    </Card>
  </Segment>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put the appropriate tags on your question and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Ok I will create a reproducible example asap, what do you mean by appropriate tags? css isn't enough?

Comment: This looks like React code, maybe add React tag also? There should be plenty of React accordion libraries out there with animation.

Comment: Thanks guys I will delete this question and create it again with an example

Answer (score 0):

Omg I'm so stupid I began to create an example but then I figured it out:

Just add to the class:

```
overflow: hidden
```

Hope it can help someone